# Question about deriving posterior distribution from normal prior and likelihood

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I am trying to understand how to derive the posterior distribution of a parameter $\mu$ given data vector $z$, $P(\mu|z)$, where 
$$
\mu \sim N(0,A)
$$
 and 
$$
 z|\mu \sim N(\mu,1).
$$

Obviously from Bayes theorem 
$$
P(\mu|z) = g(\mu) f(z|\mu) /f(z).
$$
 where
$$
f(z)= \int g(\mu) f(z|\mu) d \mu .
$$

I can write $g(\mu) f(z|\mu)$ as a pointwise product of normal densities:

$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{A}} \exp \bigg(-\frac{\mu^2+A(z-\mu)^2}{2A}\bigg)
$$

the solution is given in Efron's book on Large Scale Inference, p. 2. [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=kfE7VkqbGawC&printsec=frontcover&dq=large%20scale%20inference%20-%20empirical%20bayes%20methods&hl=de&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=large%20scale%20inference%20-%20empirical%20bayes%20methods&f=false):

$$
\mu|z \sim N(zB,B)$$ where $$B=\frac{A}{A+1}
$$

I would appreciate advice on how to approach the problem (and the answer to this question is a proof). In particular I do not understand what to do with the integral in the numerator of Bayes theorem.

**EDIT**
Following answer by @Neil_G I took a next approach:

We have: 
\begin{align}
g(\mu)   &\propto \exp\bigg(- \frac{\mu^2}{2A}\bigg)  \\[8pt]
f(z|\mu) &\propto \exp\bigg(z \mu - \frac{1}{2}(z^2+\mu^2)\bigg)
\end{align}

so
\begin{align}
P(\mu|z) &\propto \exp\bigg(- \frac{1}{2A} \mu^2 + z\mu - \frac{1}{2} z^2 - \frac{1}{2} \mu^2\bigg)  \\[8pt] 
&= \exp \bigg(-\frac{1}{2B} (\mu^2+Bz^2-2Bz \mu)\bigg)  \\[8pt]
&\propto \exp \bigg(-\frac{1}{2B} (\mu^2-2Bz \mu)\bigg)  \\[8pt]
&\propto \exp \bigg(-\frac{ (\mu - Bz)^2}{2B}\bigg) 
\end{align}

which completes the proof.

Comment: This will be much easier if you write $\mu$ in the the natural parametrization (mean times precision and precision) so that your updates to it are addition.

Comment: Also forget about $f(z)$ — just write Bayes rule with $\propto$

Comment: What do you mean by natural parameterization?

Comment: it's the parametrization $a, b$ such that a normal density can be written $f(x \mid a, b) \propto \exp(ax + bx^2)$.  Therefore, the pointwise product of densities having parameters $a_1, b_1$ and $a_2, b_2$ is simply the sum $(a_1+ a_2, b_1+b_2)$.

Comment: Complete the square w.r.t $\mu$ to find the solution.

Comment: @hard2fathom Solving the square gives me $\exp(-\mu^2/(2B) - (z^2 - 2z \mu)/2)$

Comment: Expand $\mu^2 + A(z-\mu)^2$, then collect terms, factor out the A+1, and complete the square inside the parenthesis. You should be able to obtain an expression involving $(A+1)(\mu^2 - 2\frac{Az\mu}{A+1})$. The result follows after you add and subtract the appropriate term inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
\begin{align}
    x \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) &\Leftrightarrow f(x \mid \mu, \sigma^2) \propto \exp\left(\frac\mu{\sigma^2}x -\frac1{2\sigma^2}x^2\right) & \tag{1} \\
    x \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) &\Rightarrow L(\mu \mid x, \sigma^2) \propto \exp\left(\frac{x}{\sigma^2}\mu -\frac1{2\sigma^2}\mu^2\right) & \tag{2}
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
  P(\mu) &\propto \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2A}\mu^2\right) & \text{by (1)} \\
  L(\mu \mid z) &\propto \exp\left(\mu z - \frac12\mu^2\right) & \text{by (2)} \\
  \implies P(\mu \mid z) &\propto P(\mu) L(\mu \mid z) \\
                         &\propto \exp\left(\mu z - \frac{A + 1}{2A}\mu^2\right) \\
  \implies \mu &\sim N\left(z\frac{A}{A+1}, \frac{A}{A+1}\right) & \text{by (1)}.
\end{align}

Comment: (Not sure if I made any mistakes, but this is how I would go about it.)

Comment: in the second line, don't you forget $-1/2 z^2$?

Comment: @ThomasKlausch That's a constant, so we can forget about it.

Comment: Thanks, can you check the edit to my post?

Comment: @ThomasKlausch: Is there a mistake?  Simplify it and see if our answers agree?  You can throw out $Bz^2$ since the data is fixed.

Comment: I added text to explain where I see the mistake

Comment: Ah so $Bz^2=B^2z^2=0$?

Comment: @ThomasKlausch: No, but if $f(x) \propto kg(x)$ then $f(x) \propto g(x)$.  When you renormalize everything, the scaling disappears.  Your $Bz^2$ is just a scale.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense! So that's it? :-)

Comment: @ThomasKlausch: Glad it makes sense :)  I think that's it, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

The normal prior for the mean of a normal model represents a Conjugate Prior:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior

This implies that the posterior of $\mu$ is also normal with certain parameters. This is a classical exercise in any introductory course in Bayesian statistics. The trick consists of expanding the binomial and then factorising in terms of $\mu$ in order to retrieve the normal kernel. Take a look, for instance, at the following lecture notes

http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf